# How can I disable the auto-pickup of Health Potion?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently picked up a [Bottomless Potion of the Leech](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bottomless-potion-of-the-leech) and I do not need Health Potion anymore. However, the game still auto pickup health potion for me and this is annoying. How can I disable that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.  You'll just have to keep a single stack in your inventory and drop it every once in a while.

Comment: Or sell them like every other item not work salvaging.

Comment: ... I've been throwing them on the ground instead of selling them... Why did I never think to sell them!?

Comment: @MBraedley a full stack sells for the same gold as a single pile from a monster, so its not really worth it unless you just happen to remember as you are at the merchant.  Usually my stack overflows while not in town so I just drop the full stack at that point.